# How to get raw output from SQL command in C#

Tags: c#, sql, db2

I have the following function:

```
private IDataReader ExecuteReader(OdbcCommand command) {
    var connection = new OdbcConnection(MyConnectionStringVar);
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.Connection.Open();
    command.CommandTimeout = 0;
    return command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
}
```

I can use it like this:

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM TableName";
using (var command = new OdbcCommand(query))
{
    using (var reader = ExecuteReader(command))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // get the value of ColumnName for the 
            // current row in the result set:
            // reader["ColumnName"];
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anyway I can get a raw dump of everything returned in my select statement?

I'd like to be able to use `DESCRIBE`, or similar commands, to get other info but I don't want to have to change a bunch of code just to read from the the proper column names each time. Sometimes like in `SELECT *`, I have no idea what the column names will be.

(I'm in a "coding in the dark" situation without much acceess to the server. I can't use [SQL Manager for DB2](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/db2/manager) since it was installed by a previous developer and the free trial has run out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `reader.GetValues(...)` to get all the values in the record into an `object[]`.

```
var valueArray = new object[reader.FieldCount];
reader.GetValues(valueArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question about getting the data returned by the reader, `IDataReader` provides a [column count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.fieldcount.aspx) and access to both the [column name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.getname.aspx) and [column value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.getvalue.aspx) by index.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the InfoMessage event.  It may send what you need, I don't have DB2 so that I can test.

As an aside, there are other free SQL tools you can find online since you don't have SQL Manager any more.

EDIT:  I misunderstood.  I thought you wanted output like what you get from PRINT statements and some system commands. DarkFalcon's answer is correct... you can do a simple for loop and output reader[i].  You may want to look at the column's data type to assist in formatting the output but you can easily iterate through it all.

Comment: Could you please elaborate "there are other free SQL tools"?

Comment: For example, [IBM Data Studio](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/im/data/) is completely free.

Comment: IBM Data Studio looks promising except that after you create an account on their website you have to download a 120Mb installer(!!) that downloads the 830Mb application. Is there anything a little lighter?